# Error in sending email all the solutions doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

hello every one i have big problem
 i'am using codeigniter and i am working now to sent an email

this is my controller code

class Email extends CI_Controller {

```
function index()
{
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port'=> 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'xxxxxx@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
                    'starttls'  => true,
                    'newline'   => "\r\n"

    );

    $this->load->library('email',$config);

    $this->email->from('xxxxxx@gmail.com','xxxx');
    $this->email->to('xxxxxxx@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('this is an email test');
    $this->email->message('it is working');
    $this->email->send();
}
```

}

i activate php_openssl and the port in php.ini is 25
and i have those errors

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googleemail.com:465 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server. )

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869
```

any help please ,with all respect

Comment: i  try it 
it dosen't work to

Comment: does the log still show smtp.googleemail.com ?  if so you have a disconnect somewhere, since your config shows smtp.gmail and your logs smtp.googleemail.com (which has an extra e in it, smtp.googlemail.com is correct)

Comment: yah that was the error thx alot

Answer (score 1):

Check SSL in your PHP config. If it is commented then uncomment.

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

to

```
 extension=php_openssl.dll
```

And this works for me:

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// Set to, from, message, etc.

$result = $this->email->send();
```

Comment: i enabled it and it dosen't work :(